# adding new fields and updating hidden fields

Tags: jquery

High school students can add grade GPAs for each grade that they completed.
But students need to re-submit the form, if they want to add multiple grade years. 
I want to allow them to add new fields inside the same form with a jQuery script. 
 
I found some online but they dont address to my needs; I must add numbers to the end of field names, for example `classYEAR1`, `classYEAR2`, `gpa1`, `gpa2` everytime a user adds a box. And total # of entries should added into the `totalGRADES` field. Otherwise my back end codes dont work...
I wonder if I managed to explain it correctly, I have been trying to make it work since this morning....

Look forward for your help.

```
                <form action="?Process=UpdateGrades" method="post" class="frm grades-form">
                    <fieldset>   
                        <p>
                            <label>class year</label>
                            <select name="classYEAR">
                                <option value="12">12th grade</option>
                                <option value="11">11th grade</option>
                                <option value="10">10th grade</option>
                                <option value="9">9th grade</option>
                            </select>                                    
                        </p>                                                                        
                        <p>
                            <label>GPA</label>
                            <input type="text" name="gpa" size="55" value="" />
                        </p>  
                        <p>
                            <input type="hidden" name="totalGRADES" value="1">   
                            <input type="hidden" name="x" value="p">   
                            <input type="submit" name="submıt" value="gönder" class="btn submit">
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to use the same totalGRADES hidden field for all new rows? Or have a unique one for each?

Comment: show us the code that you have tried

Comment: yes, I need the same totalGRADES.

Comment: @Efe can you share the code which is adding the new boxes

Comment: @Jude what codes, jQuery? There are quite a few on the internet but like I mentioned before none addressed my needs. But this was the closest one. http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny hi Arun its in my earlier comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding new boxes:**

First make a container to set the place to be cloned `class="clone"`, and offer a place for new boxes to appear `id="container"`

```
<div id="container"> <!--# Unique id //-->
  <div class="clone"> <!--# Class, after cloning it is duplicated, so id should not be used //-->
    <p>
      <label>class year</label>
      <select name="classYEAR">
        <option value="12">12th grade</option>
        <option value="11">11th grade</option>
        <option value="10">10th grade</option>
        <option value="9">9th grade</option>
      </select>                                    
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>GPA</label>
      <input type="text" name="gpa" size="55" value="" />
    </p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, the code below binds to a add button with a cloning function:

```
$('#addButton').click(function() {

  count = $('div.clone').length;
  # Counts the total number of boxes. Modify with +1 or something as you need

  $('div.clone:first')
    .clone() # Clone the code
    .find('select')  
      .attr('name', 'classYEAR' + count)   # Modify the select name with a number subfix
      .end()  # Back to parent 
    .find('input')
      .attr('name', 'gpa' + count)    # Modify the input name with a number subfix
      .end()  # Back to parent      
    .appendTo('#container');  # Put in container
});
```

**To update the totalGRADES**, first add an `id` for easier searching

```
<input id="totalGRADES" type="hidden" name="totalGRADES" value="1">
```

Then bind this to onsubmit

```
var count = $('div.clone').length;   # This counts the total number of boxes
$('#totalGRADES').val(count);  # This updates the value of the hidden input
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes that you have some kind of add button with an id, just change the "addButton" name to whatever the ID of the button you are using to add fields is.

```
$('#addButton').click(function() {
  var count = parseInt($('[name="totalGrades"]').val());
  count = count + 1;
  $('fieldset').append('<p><label>class year</label><select name="classYEAR'+count+'">{{options}}</select></p>{{GPA Fields}}');
  $('[name="totalGrades"]').val(count);
});
```

The first line adds an action listener to the add button which triggers the function inside it when clicked. The next two lines fetches the current number of entries and increment it by one. The next line after that appends the html code to the fieldset element and substitutes in that incremented counter where relevant to set the name attributes. The second to last line updates the hidden totalGrades field on the page with the new count.

There is probably a more elegant solution that doesn't require you to hard code the HTML in the javascript using .clone() or the like, but this is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your message. However, it does not update the totalGrades field. Same problem with what I have